# how to replicate iOS mail new message animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

how to replicate this animation where user can scroll the (new message)view controller up and down on top of the (inbox)view controller and the (inbox)view controller appears to be stacked behind.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/uikit_dynamics) to achieve the same effect. 
Use UIAttachmentBehavior to tie the new "card" (VC's view snapshot) and a relative center point. Use UICollisionBehavior between the card and borders of the screen to prevent the card moving sideways.

Comment: how would I be able to replicate the retreating behavior of the background view(inbox view. when the new message view is presented the inbox view retreats towards the background?

Comment: @j.doe Kindly have a look at this lib which does exactly what you're looking for: https://github.com/jobandtalent/CardStackController